# If $f$ is integrable then so is $1/f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a,b]$ with $|f| \geq p > 0 $ for $a \leq x \leq b$. Show that $\frac{1}{f}$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$.

I was told the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality might be useful here, but can't figure out what to do with it. Since $f$ is integrable, it is bounded, and since a lower bound $p$ is already given, call the upper bound $M$. Then by Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$ \Bigl|\int_a^b 1 \,dx\Bigr|^2 \leq \int_a^b |f|^2 \,dx \int_a^b \frac{1}{|f|^2} \,dx$$

simplifying and using the fact that $ p \leq |f| \leq M$,

$$\frac{b-a}{M} \leq \int_a^b \frac{1}{|f|^2} \,dx \leq \frac{b-a}{p^2}$$

From here I don't know what to do with this information (if it is even useful). My only other thoughts on this problem would to be to try and show that $U(P,\frac{1}{f}) - L(P, \frac{1}{f}) < \epsilon $. I would love to say that the Uppper sums of $f$ are the lower sums of $\frac{1}{f} $ and a similar thing for the lower sums, but I do not think this is always true.

Comment: Right, the upper sums of $f$ aren't the lower sums of $1/f$. But they are closely related.

Comment: Since $\left|\frac{1}{f(a)}-\frac{1}{f(b)}\right|=\frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{|f(a)f(b)|}\leq \frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{p^2}$, $U(P,\frac{1}{f})-L(P,\frac{1}{f})$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{p^2}\left(U(P,f)-L(P,f)\right)$.